# Access webservices using RCurl CurlPerform: Getting HTTP 500 error

Tags: r, web-services, rcurl, http-status-code-500

I am trying to use a webservice using RCurl package.

This webservice 'https://ngcsi.contigohosting.com/Entrader_Dev/wcfservices/TradingService.svc' has a lot of get methods which can be accessed only by

authentication and hence I am passing the user name and password in the header.

```
h=basicTextGatherer()
headerFields =
    c(c(Accept="text/xml", Accept="multipart/*",
        'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"),
      SOAPAction = "https://ngcsi.contigohosting.com/Entrader_Dev/wcfservices/TradingService.svc?wsdl")

body = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:con="http://entrader.contigoenergy.com/Contigo.Entrader.Service">\
    <soapenv:Header>\
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"\
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">\
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-37"\
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">\
<wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>\
<wsse:Password
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>\
</wsse:UsernameToken>\
</wsse:Security>\
</soapenv:Header>\
<soapenv:Body>\
</soapenv:Body>\
</soapenv:Envelope>\n'

curlPerform(url = "https://ngcsi.contigohosting.com/Entrader_Dev/wcfservices/TradingService.svc",
            httpheader = headerFields,
            postfields = body, 
            writefunction = h$update,
            verbose=TRUE
)

body=h$value()
```

I get a HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error while executing the above and below is the body content

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2017-07-25T15:14:00.856Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2017-07-25T15:19:00.856Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-GB">The message with Action 'https://ngcsi.contigohosting.com/Entrader_Dev/wcfservices/TradingService.svc?wsdl' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAPAction should have a method and in this instance could be any of the following as per the wsdl used above.

```
http://entrader.contigoenergy.com/Contigo.Entrader.Service/TradingService/GetTrade
```

`http://entrader.contigoenergy.com/Contigo.Entrader.Service/TradingService/GetByFilterTrade`

So, the new code should look like the following

```
h=basicTextGatherer()
headerFields =
    c(c(Accept="text/xml", Accept="multipart/*",
        'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"),
      SOAPAction = "http://entrader.contigoenergy.com/Contigo.Entrader.Service/TradingService/GetTrade")

body = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:con="http://entrader.contigoenergy.com/Contigo.Entrader.Service">\
    <soapenv:Header>\
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"\
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">\
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-37"\
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">\
<wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>\
<wsse:Password
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>\
</wsse:UsernameToken>\
</wsse:Security>\
</soapenv:Header>\
<soapenv:Body>\
</soapenv:Body>\
</soapenv:Envelope>\n'

curlPerform(url = "https://ngcsi.contigohosting.com/Entrader_Dev/wcfservices/TradingService.svc",
            httpheader = headerFields,
            postfields = body, 
            writefunction = h$update,
            verbose=TRUE
)

body=h$value()
```

The above code works and I am able to get appropriate response from the webservice although I have not mentioned anything in the body in the example stated.